# Is it bad practice to stack animations on top of each other?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to accomplish a kind of "fade" animation for a web project that utilizes two images (without having to use a gif file). The images are exact copies of each other, except they have different fill colors. They are very simple images in the sense that the only color they have is that one fill color, different for each.

My goal is to make a sort of "passive" transition that will trigger when the user's viewport is on a certain part of the page. It should simply look like the image's color is changing and also scaling up slightly in size. Setting the `animation-direction: alternate;` and `animation-iteration-count: infinite;`  allows it to look like the image is expanding and changing color and returning back to its original state.

I have it set so the two images are always overlapping each other with different Z-indexes, so image1 is in front while image2 is behind it. With the CSS @keyframes rule, I can make it so image1 slowly decreases in opacity, revealing image2 and giving it a feel of a very slight color change. I also apply a different @keyframes rule that handles the scaling of the image. Code below:

```
<div>
    <img class="crane-origami front" src="assets/crane.png">
    <img class="crane-origami back" src="assets/craneAlternate.png">
</div>
```

With the following styles:

```
.crane-origami {
    position: absolute;
}

.crane-origami.front {
    z-index: 2;
    animation: breathe 2s infinite alternate, makeTransparent 2s infinite alternate;
}

.crane-origami.back {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
    animation: breathe 2s infinite alternate;
}
```

and @keyframes:

```
@keyframes makeTransparent {
    from {}
    to {opacity: 0};
}
@keyframes breathe {
    from {}
    to {transform: scale(1.2);}
}
```

I was wondering if there is any better way of achieving this transition, since this solution seems kind of dirty. I don't like the fact that I have to apply the same animation to two different images just so they can be on top of each other at all times. I guess a bigger problem would be if one of the animations moved one of the images from one place to another, I would have to apply the same animation to another image so it stays with the original. Maybe it would be better to apply those "moving" animations to the containing `div` and simply apply the `makeTransparent` animation to the one image, but it still doesn't seem like the best solution. Also, I am afraid that different loading times will make the animation start-time not line up and the effect will not be exact.

Comment: My advice is to use `<svg>` vectors instead of images. They are lighter and processed faster. Their only problem is they need to be placed inline so `currentColor` works as intended (inherits color from parent element - which you can style using CSS).

Comment: If the animations are used separately and semantically distinct, then keep them separate. If this is the only place you use them or they are always used together, combine the animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I would go with a `div` and a pseudo.

Here both images scales with the `div` and the opacity on the pseudo.

*Another option is, if you images does not have any transparent areas, that the colored part, where it differs, could be set to transparent and then you could animate a background color and only the need of a single image. This could of course be done using a SVG as well, animate its fill color, so the choice of image type is more about what's practical based on the image content*

```css
.crane-origami {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/150/f0f);
}
.crane-origami:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/150/f00);
}
.crane-origami {
  animation: breathe 2s infinite alternate;
}
.crane-origami:before {
  opacity: 1;
  animation: trans 2s infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes trans {
  from {}
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes breathe {
  from {}
  to {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="crane-origami">
</div>
```